# Ошибка при попытки выполнения команды npm run build (Next), связанная с convex

Tags: reactjs, npm, next

При попытке выполнить команду npm run build выдает ошибку

```
   ▲ Next.js 14.1.1
   - Environments: .env.local

   Creating an optimized production build ...
Compiler edge-server unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Skipping linting
   Checking validity of types  ..Failed to compile.

./node_modules/convex/src/server/router.ts:135:33
Type error: Type 'IterableIterator<[string, PublicHttpAction]>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.

  133 |       const prefixes =
  134 |         this.prefixRoutes.get(method) || new Map<string, PublicHttpAction>();
> 135 |       for (const [prefix, _] of prefixes.entries()) {
      |                                 ^
  136 |         if (spec.path.startsWith(prefix)) {
  137 |           throw new Error(
  138 |             `${spec.method} path ${spec.path} is shadowed by pathPrefix ${prefix}`,
```

Я использую convex в связке с clerk, не понимаю с чем может быть связана ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: `when using ... with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher` таргет укажите в каком-то конфиге или пускаче

Comment: да я прочитал, я уже и в папке convex в корне проекта пробовал, и в node_modules залез, все равно не хочет

Comment: tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions -> target (es2015 или посвежее)